# countdown Timer - Ionic 3

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I'm making an application that has a countdown timer. The problem is. When I press `startTimer()` will countdown. But when back to the previous page. Then press enter. It's not showing up, I Want to switch to another page or switching to another app. Time will continue to work and continue to run until the timing is the same as the clock application of the iPhone or Android.

```
  startTimer() {
    this.isStart = true;
    // var timer = 60; //Second  
    var hours;
    var minutes;
    var seconds;
    this.t = setInterval(() => {
      if (!this.isPause) {
        var hours;
        var minutes;
        var seconds;
        hours = Math.floor(this.time / 3600);
        minutes = Math.floor(hours / 60);
        seconds = Math.floor(this.time % 60);
        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        this.output = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        this.percent = this.time / this.time * 100;
        this.increment = 180 / 100;
        const progress = 'rotate(' + this.increment * this.percent + 'deg)';
        this.transform = progress;
        this.fixTransform = progress;
        this.time--;
        if (this.time === 0) {
          clearInterval(this.t);
        }
      }
    }, 1000);

    console.log('start');
  }
```

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: you should give more context around how your app is organized and where this code snippet live currently.